# "Removing" PDF embedded fonts without PostScript

Tags: pdf, fonts, postscript

I have some PDFs that have embedded fonts, which won't display in Preview in OS X (as far as I know, due to a bug in Preview).

To fix this, I ran the PDF through `pdf2ps` and then back through `ps2pdf`, which fixed things in Preview, while still leaving the text intact (i.e. selectable). Adobe Reader shows the same  embedded fonts as before in document properties (only this time it's a subset of the font).

However, one of my PDF has elements with opacities, which PostScript can't handle (it just rasterises the whole thing).

**My question:** Can I achieve the same effect (with regards to the fonts) as `pdf2ps`/`ps2pdf` but **without** converting to PostScript? Or just in a way that doesn't break when opacities are involved?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/166024/substitute-a-font-in-a-pdf-document

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after, I'm afraid. What I need is a process that can be executed programatically that does whatever `pdf2ps | ps2pdf` does, but **without** tripping up on opacities.