# Changing PDF Fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have a couple of questions related to pdf editing.
(1) Is there a way to change a font in a pdf doc preserving the font attributes without having to select paragraphs with different font types manually? Maybe this is related to the fact that italics/bold face/etc are contained in different files...
(2) How can I select the WHOLE document in the Edit Document Text Tool?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Go back to the original document. PDF is not really suitable for being editable in this sense. If you don't have access to the original document try exporting to Word, change things there and recreate the PDF (the results depend a lot on how well the original PDF has been created).

Comment: I'll try the Word conversion. Thanks for your reply, Max.

Comment: Related (or duplicate): http://superuser.com/questions/926340/how-to-change-efficiently-a-font-throughout-the-entire-pdf-document and http://superuser.com/questions/166024/substitute-a-font-in-a-pdf-document