# How can I efficiently change a typeface throughout a whole PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat

Suppose that a PDF contains typefaces X and Y throughout. [This](http://www.iceni.com/blog/how-to-change-a-pdf-font-quickly/) refers to the following command that I don't see in my Adobe Acrobat:

> Edit -> Find & Replace -> Replace Font

How can I change only X to Z without editing each text box?

Answer (score 2):

The editing capabilities in Acrobat DC are improved considerably over Acrobat XI, and that may actually be worth the upgrade cost.

However, changing fonts in the PDF may cause problems, unless the run-length of the replacement font is exactly the same as the one of the original font. Otherwise, you may end up in tedious adjustment tasks.

Therefore, it is much better to do the edits (which include the font selection) in the original document (and if you don't have it, but have the permission to noodle around in the document, export it to Word or so, and make the edits there).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've done this, is by converting the PDF to another format (usually word), changed the font and fixed any small problem, and then converting it back to PDF. This works almost perfectly if you are working with a normal PDF file and not a scanned one. I would recommend Acrobat DC as it converts the PDFs better. This is what results to me at least...